# VS Code fails to automatically recognize AZ-3166 dev kit

Tags: iot-devkit

According to the documentation,:

> Start VS Code and then connect the DevKit to your computer. VS Code automatically finds the DevKit and opens an introduction page.

But this is not happening. No error is thrown, but nothing happens. I can hear a tone from the computer when the `AZ-3166` is plugged-in. It shows up as a storage device on the PC. And the Arduino IDE is able to recognize it.

But VS Code ignores it and does not take me to the introductory page, so I am unable to complete the documented process of connecting to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I come across this issue as well.

You can resolve this manually by pressing F1 and typing in the command Arduino: Board Manager. From there look up MXChip - Microsoft Azure IoT Developer Kit and install the latest version. From there you should be able to proceed as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a workspace open? If so, try closing it (File > Close Workspace) then close VSCode, reopen and connect your device.

It works for me. Good luck.